# Oracle11g - Problemas comando SELECT

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Isto acontece após eu executar a seguinte linha de `SQL`:

```
/* Listar todas as reuniões do utilizador onde esteja convidado*/
String sql = "SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA FROM MEETING AS M, MEETING_LIST AS ML WHERE (M.ID=ML.ID_MEETING AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR=( SELECT ID FROM UTILIZADOR WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR='"+ parcel.getUsername()+"' ) AND ML.STATUS=1 AND ML.INVITE=1)";
toClient = new AbstractMessage(database.submitQuery(sql));
```

A tabela `MEETING` tem os seguintes atributos:

- ID, TITLE, OUTCOME, DIA, HORA, LOCALIZACAO

A tabela `MEETING_LIST` tem os seguintes atributos:

- ID, ID_MEETING, ID_UTILIZADOR, INVITE, STATUS

A tabela `UTILIZADOR` tem os seguintes atributos:

- ID, NOMEUTILIZADOR, PALAVRACHAVE

A tabela `MEETING_LIST` é uma tabela que cruza os utilizadores e as reuniões (many to many).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A própria mensagem de erro está dizendo o que está acontecendo.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Significa que algo na construção da sua SQL fez o ORACLE entender que chegou ao final do comando antes de realmente estar no final do comando.

Creio que o seu problema são os aliases que você colocou. Na verdade você não deve colocar "**MEETING AS M**" e sim apenas "**MEETING M**" a palavra reservada "**AS**" deve ser usada apenas para definir os alias das colunas e não redefinir o nome da tabela a ser usada no comando SQL.

Tente o seguinte.

```
String sql = "SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA FROM MEETING M, MEETING_LIST ML WHERE (M.ID=ML.ID_MEETING AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR=( SELECT ID FROM UTILIZADOR WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR='"+ parcel.getUsername()+"' ) AND ML.STATUS=1 AND ML.INVITE=1)";
toClient = new AbstractMessage(database.submitQuery(sql));
```

Tente ter sempre em mãos alguma IDE para gerenciamento de bancos de dados como por exemplo o [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html?gclid=CjwKEAjwzqKiBRCAydTZzOLi9CISJACm3irWQb-Cf88psLUGZrzKSenZC1v_-jqysvFP9U9C9ohU8xoC4mbw_wcB) e sempre que ocorrer esses erros execute seus comandos SQL na IDE, ela ajuda muito na agilidade em encontrar os erros.

Answer (score 2):

Solução é retirar o `AS`.

```
String sql = "SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA FROM MEETING M, MEETING_LIST ML WHERE (M.ID=ML.ID_MEETING AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR=( SELECT ID FROM UTILIZADOR WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR='"+ parcel.getUsername()+"' ) AND ML.STATUS=1 AND ML.INVITE=1)";
                toClient = new AbstractMessage(database.submitQuery(sql));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem dois parenteses a mais na clausula WHERE ocasionando o erro:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA
  FROM MEETING AS M, MEETING_LIST AS ML
WHERE (M.ID = ML.ID_MEETING AND
    ML.ID_UTILIZADOR =
       (SELECT ID<br>
           FROM UTILIZADOR<br>
          WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR = '"+ parcel.getUsername()+"') AND
       ML.STATUS = 1 AND ML.INVITE = 1)
```

Tente este:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA
  FROM MEETING AS M, MEETING_LIST AS ML
 WHERE M.ID = ML.ID_MEETING
   AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR =
       (SELECT ID
          FROM UTILIZADOR
         WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR = '"+ parcel.getUsername()+"')
   AND ML.STATUS = 1
   AND ML.INVITE = 1
```

Comment: Use quatro espaço para formtar códigos ou selecione o texto e click no botão `{ }`

Answer (score -1):

Quando vc executa o sql em um cliente oracle da certo ou errado? 
se vc jogar o sql no squirrel ou outro cliente de sql da erro?

> SELECT M.ID, M.TITLE, M.DIA, M.HORA FROM MEETING AS M, MEETING_LIST AS ML WHERE (M.ID=ML.ID_MEETING AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR=( SELECT ID FROM UTILIZADOR WHERE NOMEUTILIZADOR='id_do_utilizador' ) AND ML.STATUS=1 AND ML.INVITE=1)

Se o sql estiver dando erro no cliente de sql entao uma estrategia de depuração,seria vc executar a query em partes, dessa forma vc vai saber onde é o ponto em que o erro ocorre.

Tenta ver se essa query aqui resolve:

> SELECT
>      M.ID,
>      M.TITLE,
>      M.DIA,
>      M.HORA 
>   FROM
>      MEETING AS M,
>      MEETING_LIST AS ML 
>   WHERE
>      M.ID=ML.ID_MEETING 
>      AND ML.ID_UTILIZADOR=(
>         SELECT
>            ID 
>         FROM
>            UTILIZADOR 
>         WHERE
>            NOMEUTILIZADOR='1' 
>      ) 
>      AND ML.STATUS=1 
>      AND ML.INVITE=1